# Circuit Simulator is being funky

Tags: current-source, circuit-analysis

This circuit simulator called "iCircuit" for mac users is showing some weird readings. It's showing a reading of 2.4mA and i'm getting 6mA in my calculations for this circuit I threw up. Am I missing something here??

18V / (2k + 1k) = 6mA

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's terrible. So what was your question again?

Comment: A schematic with designators for all the components ("R1", "R2", ...) and numbers/names for all the nodes would make it much easier to answer this question.

Comment: Am I missing something or is my calculation correct.

Comment: Your calculation relies on an assumption that the negative terminal of the voltage source is at 0 V. Why did you make that assumption?

Comment: simulation numbers are right.

Comment: I'll attach a more clearer image showing the nodes but could you explain where I went wrong in my calculations. My procedure was turning the voltage source into a current source which gave me 18V / (1k+2k) = 6mA. From there I combined 3mA with 6mA since they are in parallel with each other giving me 3mA + 6mA = 9mA. From there I used the current divider formula giving me Ix = ( Rtotal / Rx )I. After substitution (1.2k / 3k)9mA = 3.6mA

Comment: I see it now. I made the mistake of assuming that on the negative terminal of the 18V supple was at ground potential (0V) which it clearly is not. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

The simulation shows 2.4 mA through the battery. That is correct. Measurement of voltages in this circuit needs to be **with reference to the Ground symbol**, not the battery. If you recalculate accordingly, the results will match the simulation.

The simulator specified is almost identical to the [Falstad circuit simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/), so a quick check using Falstad should validate that iCircuit is correct.